# Drawing of balls from box A to box B and back to box A

Tags: probability

Box A contains 7 blue balls and 5 yellow balls. Box B contains 3 blue balls and 7 yellow balls. One ball is removed at random from Box A and placed in Box B. After thoroughly mixing the balls, a ball is drawn at random from box B and placed back into A.

Find the probability that at the end of the experiment, box A has (a) exactly 7 blue and 5 yellow balls, (b) twice as many blue balls as yellow balls.

My solution:

For part (a):

Scenario 1: Drawing a blue ball from Box A initially
Probability of drawing a blue ball from Box A: $\frac{7}{12}$

After moving a blue ball from A to B, Box A has 6 blue and 5 yellow balls.

Probability of drawing a blue ball from Box B: $\frac{4}{14}$

After moving this blue ball back to Box A, it will have 7 blue and 5 yellow balls.

So, for this scenario:
P = $\frac{7}{12} \times \frac{4}{14}$

Scenario 2: Drawing a yellow ball from Box A initially

Probability of drawing a yellow ball from Box A: $\frac{5}{12}$

After moving a yellow ball from A to B, Box A has 7 blue and 4 yellow balls.

Probability of drawing a blue ball from Box B: $\frac{3}{14}$

So for this scenario:

P = $\frac{5}{12} \times \frac{3}{14}$

P( exactly 7 blue and 5 yellow in A) = $\frac{7}{12} \times \frac{4}{14}$ + $\frac{5}{12} \times \frac{3}{14}$ = $\frac{4}{21}$

For part (b):

P(Twice as many blue as yellow in A)= $\frac{7}{12} \times \frac{4}{14}$

P(Twice as many blue as yellow in A) = $\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2}{7} = \frac{2}{21}$

However, I checked against the correct answer, both part (a) and (b) are wrong. They should be $\frac{17}{33}$ for part (a) and $\frac{5}{44}$ for part (b).

What was done wrong? Appreciate for anyone's help. Thanks

Comment: Once a blue ball has moved from $A$ to $B$, $B$ holds $4$ blue and $7$ yellow.  Thus the probability of picking blue from $B$ is $\frac 4{11}$.

Answer (score 0):

In (a) your computation of the probability of drawing a blue ball from box B are both wrong (they should be 4/11 and 3/11). Also in the case where a yellow ball was drawn from the box A, you want the probability of drawing a **yellow** ball from box B. This gives you $$P = \frac{7}{12} \cdot\frac{4}{11} + \frac{5}{12}\cdot\frac{8}{11} =  \frac{17}{33}$$

For (b) you want to compute the probability of having twice as many blue balls in box A than yellow balls. As the number of balls at the end in the box A is still 12, you deduce that you want to compute the probability of having 8 blue balls and 4 yellow balls in box A.

The only way to attain this configuration is if you first remove a yellow ball from A and then you add a blue ball to A (which is equivalent to removing a blue ball from B). The odds of the first are $\frac{5}{12}$. The odds of the second in knowing that a yellow ball was removed from A (thus added to B) are $\frac{3}{11}$.

You end up having that $$P = \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{3}{11} = \frac{5}{44}$$

Comment: Understood and Thank you for part (a). May I ask how should I do part (b), I am kind of confused.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.